# `Unknown method parameter type` error while running QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Consider the slightly modified `birthday_party.h` [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-referenceexamples-methods-example.html) from the standard QT example lists below.

In the code below, I have added a stub `test()` function which just prints the name of the person using the pointer passed to it.

```
#ifndef BIRTHDAYPARTY_H
#define BIRTHDAYPARTY_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlListProperty>

#include "person.h"

class BirthdayParty : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Person *host READ host WRITE setHost)
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<Person> guests READ guests)
public:
    BirthdayParty(QObject *parent = 0);

    Person *host() const;
    void setHost(Person *);

    QQmlListProperty<Person> guests();
    int guestCount() const;
    Person *guest(int) const;

    Q_INVOKABLE Person* invite(const QString &name);
    Q_INVOKABLE void test( Person* p);

private:
    Person *m_host;
    QList<Person *> m_guests;
};

#endif // BIRTHDAYPARTY_H
```

The definition for `test()` is

```
void BirthdayParty :: test(Person* p)
{
  QString qname = p->name();
  std::cout << qname.toUtf8().constData() << std::endl;
}
```

My QML file where I call test is

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import People 1.0


BirthdayParty {
    host: Person { name: "Bob Jones" ; shoeSize: 12 }

    guests: [
        Person { name: "Leo Hodges" },
        Person { name: "Jack Smith" },
        Person { name: "Anne Brown" },
        Person { name : "Gaurish Telang"}
    ]

    Component.onCompleted:
       {
         test(guests[0])
        }
}
```

Now the above code compiles and runs just fine. However, if I add the `const` qualifier in front of `Person* p` in the argument list of `test()`
I get errors from QML at run-time! (i.e. runtime  barfs if the signature for test in both headers and .cpp is `void test(const Person* p)`)

The error I get at runtime is

```
qrc:example.qml:17: Error: Unknown method parameter type: const Person*
```

It seems my error is identical to the one reported [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45417) on the bug-reports website. I am using Qt 5.10, the latest version of Qt.

**EDIT**

The `Person` and `BirthdayParty` types are being registered as follows

```
 qmlRegisterType<BirthdayParty>("People", 1,0, "BirthdayParty");
 qmlRegisterType<Person>("People", 1,0, "Person");
```

Comment: How do you register your items?

Comment: @folibis Please see edit. I did not change how I registered the types, while experimenting with adding the `const` qualifier above. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, as I understand the last versions of Qt had changed object casting from QML to Qt and vice versa. Sometimes it was able to use pointers to object, references etc. It looks that now it's different and you have to specify the used type explicitly.
In your case I guess you should add the following line to items registration:

```
qRegisterMetaType<Person*>("const Person*");
```

Btw, I advice you to use references instead of pointers since it eliminates the ambiguity.